# Finding the Nth previous row based on criteria - dynamic LAG

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this SQL challenge
I have a table which looks like that (I've just got a message from the site saying I can't post the image right here, so please use the link)

[image]

The challenge is to identify the nearest N-th previous row where the value of NEW_BATCH_FLAG = 1 and to "spread" the value of "date of current transaction" of THAT  row for all the following rows where NEW_BATCH_FLAG = 0 (till we'll meet the next row with NEW_BATCH_FLAG = 1 )

As you can (hopefully :)) see in the image, the first row has  NEW_BATCH_FLAG = 1  so I should "spread" it's date (1-jun-2020) for the 2 next rows where  NEW_BATCH_FLAG = 0, but the problem is that for the first one i have to go one row back, and for the second one - 2 rows back.

So the challenge is to calculate for each given row - how many rows I have to go back till I hit the nearest  NEW_BATCH_FLAG = 1 row.

This "distance" will be further used in the LAG function as the argument for offset.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), so that can be copied in order to create test data. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: So for the "lag of ..." entries you want to see `2020-06-01` as the "start of batch date"?

Comment: Please read the guidelines on the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Try doing the `MAX(CASE WHEN new_batch_flag = 1 THEN  trandate END) OVER (PARTITION BY whatever ORDER BY whatever ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` - with it you basically null all the dates that are not a batch start then pull the max one out of a window that always extends between the start of the partition and the current row. Note; you didn't post any column names or even what db you have so it's a comment because your db might not even support this.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a scalar sub-query, but it won't be very efficient:

```sql
select t1.transaction_date, 
       t1.new_batch_flag,
       case new_batch_flag
          when 1 then t1.transaction_date
          else (select max(t2.transaction_date)
                from the_table t2
                where t2.new_batch_flag = 1
                  and t2.transaction_date < t1.transaction_date)
       end as start_date_of_batch
from the_table t1;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec9625721c9782ecfadf54fe2551d79a)

With Postgres I would do it like this:

```
select transaction_date, 
       new_batch_flag,
       case new_batch_flag
          when 1 then transaction_date
          else max(transaction_date) filter (where new_batch_flag = 1) over (order by transaction_date)
       end as start_of_batch
from the_table;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3a84aca38b302bc204f0490595b19046)

Comment: Your solution makes perfect sense (thank you), only 1 problem - my T_1 table is actually a CTE and  I think in this case I can't use a correlated subquery , it  always gives me an error (because the inner subquery doesn't know cte exists). I'm using PL SQL

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a cumulative max with some conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when new_batch_flag = 1 then transaction_date end) over (order by transaction_date) as start_date_of_batch
from t;
```